# Dry Erase Marker Issue: Mixed Colors

Tags: office-supplies, color

I had a cousin who scribbled a red marker over a black marker drawing. Now the red marker can have a black tint to it (sometimes it’s a little black). Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drag the red marker over a paper towel while rotating it. Do it a few times over a day or two. The rough absorbent surface will help remove the black flakes of pigment.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the advice. I’ll give it a shot when I can use the whiteboard